# Completing Binance Spot Grid pine script code

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In general, the code represents a simple Binance grid trading strategy. I'm still learning pine script and in process of writing this code. I'm stuck at this point, and not sure how to proceed, pine script editor gives out error of compilation, perhaps kind people here could explain what exactly I'm doing wrong and how this code can be written properly.

Thank you everyone in advance!

```
//@version=5
strategy("Binance Spot Grid Trading", overlay=true)

// Grid parameters
gridSize = input(10, "Grid Size")
upperLimit = input(10000, "Upper Limit")
lowerLimit = input(5000, "Lower Limit")

// Calculate grid levels
gridLevels = ta.range(floor(na(upperLimit / gridSize)) * gridSize, ceil(na(lowerLimit / gridSize)) * gridSize, gridSize)

// Place buy and sell orders at grid levels
for level in gridLevels
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when = ta.crossover(close, level))
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short, when = ta.crossunder(close, level))

// Exit conditions
strategy.exit("Exit Long", "Buy", when = ta.crossunder(close, gridLevels[1]))
strategy.exit("Exit Short", "Sell", when = ta.crossover(close, gridLevels[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with this code.

Math functions like `floor` and `ceil` have their own workspace called `math`. So you should be calling them as `math.floor()` and `math.ceil()`.

`ta.range` expects two arguments but you are passing three.

```
ta.range(source, length) → series float
```

Also, it returns `series float` or `series int` but you are using it as if was returning an array.

So, your for loop structure is not valid also.

```
for level in gridLevels
```

Your use of `strategy.exit` is also doesn't seem to be correct. It looks like you are trying to close a position conditionally and if that is the case, you should be using `strategy.close()` instead.

However, knowing this strategy, you want to exit if the price touches a grid level. In that case, you should call the `strategy.exit()` function but use its `limit` and `stop` arguments to set your exit price.